# How to get preview picture using directshow?

Tags: c#, directshow

I have an application running on Windows Compact Embedded 7 written in C#.
My camera is set to have resolution of 2048*1536 and I have a control on my win form which is 360*240.
Problem is on this control I just see part of the picture, I don't see full picture.

How can I set the camera to compress or re-size image according to my control size so that I can see the full picture in preview?

I can share code if that is needed.

Comment: Do you use Microsoft DirectShow? Can you show how you build your filtergraph?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you use `VMRRenderer` to display video on concrete part of UI. The `VMRRenderer` has `SetVideoPosition` which will do resizing.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd390962%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I don't find this function where is it?